# Objective-C complains about expecting "{" at the end of input, and a missing return statement

Tags: objective-c, compilation

Trying to compile an Objective-C program from the internet. I'm a python programmer primarily, but it seems odd to me that Objective-C is looking for a "{" at the *end* of input. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "HeartMonitorWindow.h"
#import "Serial.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  HeartMonitorWindow *window;
  Serial *serial;
  uint8_t value;

  window = [[HeartMonitorWindow alloc] init];
  serial = [[Serial alloc] init];

  [serial open:"/dev/ttyASM0"];

  while(1)
  {
    [window draw];
    value = [serial readByte];
    [window pause];
    [window update:value];
    if ([window shouldQuit]) { 
      break; 
    }
  }


  [serial close];

  return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors breaking the compile:

```
heart_monitor.c:35:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
 }
 ^
heart_monitor.c:35:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

What's going on wrong here?

**Edit:** Contents of HeartMonitorWindow.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>

#define SIGNAL_LENGTH 128

@interface HeartMonitorWindow:NSObject
{
  SDL_Surface *screen;
  SDL_Rect background_rect;
  SDL_Rect marker_rect;
  Uint32 clear_color;
  Uint32 marker_color;
  int posx;
  Uint32 dot_colors[SIGNAL_LENGTH];
  int values[SIGNAL_LENGTH];
  //int value;
  int current;
  int index;
}

- (id)init;
- (void)delloc;
- (void)draw;
- (void)pause;
- (void)update:(int)value;
- (bool)shouldQuit;

@end
```

And Serial.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Serial:NSObject
{
  int fd;
  struct termios oldtio;
  struct termios newtio;
}

- (id)init;
- (void)delloc;
- (int)open:(char *)device;
- (int)send:(char *)packet;
- (uint8_t)readByte;
- (void)close;

@end
```

And it's being compiled with:

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` `pkg-config --cflags --libs glut gl glu sdl` -lgnustep-base -lobjc heart_monitor.c -o hrmon
```

Comment: You probably have some hidden bad character in the file. Delete the last line and type it in again.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but it didn't seem to make any difference. These {} thingies are really wracking my python-y brain!

Comment: Well I copied and pasted your code above with no problem. Strange.

Comment: There could be a problem in HeartMonitorWindow.h or Serial.h.

Comment: @zaph Thanks for the tip. I included both of those. I also tried re-typing all of the last-lines and ending-}'s in all of the files with the same errors on compilation. I'm compiling with: gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` `pkg-config --cflags --libs glut gl glu sdl` -lgnustep-base -lobjc heart_monitor.c -o hrmon

Comment: gcc is not current, you should use llvm. If you are not using Xcode things are going to be more difficult because Xcode has good error and warning messages that help as well as analyzer. Of course a Mac is going to be required for Xcode.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. There isn't any Xcode.